# get thread of gmail from API

Tags: javascript, multithreading, email, google-api, gmail

I want to get all the thread (mail body) of the mail by Google API like now i used below code for fetching the thread (mail body) of the mail. its working fine but if only 2 users send mail to each other. if we add any third person the thread (mail body) will not come by API.

```
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.threads.get({
    'userId': 'MyUserId',
    'id': 'MyMessageID',
    'format': 'full'
});



request.execute( function( response )
{
    var fLenght = response.messages.length - 1;
    console.log(response.messages[fLenght].payload.variable.body.data)
}
```

If user1 and user2 (only 2 users) added in the thread (mail body) then its working perfect. but if we add user3 (3 users) then thread (mail body) is not coming. I have wondered all the API's but not any success yet. Can you please let me know how i get all thread of more than 2 members.